# How can one use Reporting Services against a log shipped database?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, ssrs

Using MS SQL SERVER 2005. I have log shipped the ReportServer database to the secondary server in Standby/Readonly. I seem to be unable to use Reporting Services on the secondary database because it complains about the ReportServer database being Read Only.

Is there some way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in SQL 2005 Enterprise Edition.  This may be a limitation of pricing and fees to honor that functionality.

Answer (score 0):

you'd better of replicating the database you want to report on, that should work in any version. It can be a bit of a pain to setup but once you have set it up its very reliable, and should work on any version (apart from probably sql express)

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to "use" the log-shipped version of the database on the secondary server in this way.  You may be able to run select statements to retrieve data from it using the SQL Server Management Studio, but actually running the Reporting Services component of SQL Server from it will not be possible.

When running, SSRS may actually insert or update data behind the scenes and not just select data - for example, new records are inserted into the ExecutionLog table when a user opens a report.  This is simply not possible with a read-only database.